# What is the most accepted way to implement a SOAP service in Rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap

datanoise-actionwebservice was what I used last time I needed one.  What is current opinion on SOAP and Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datanoise-actionwebservice is still the way to go.